# how to handle error readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:991)

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the string to Double like:

```
Double no_of_leaves_form=Double.parseDouble(leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves());
```

and data type of NO_of_leaves in database is varchar.
but I am getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:991)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at com.dz.hrportal.worker.EmpLeaveApplyWorker.validateUser(EmpLeaveApplyWorker.java:42)
    at com.dz.hrportal.controller.EmpLeaveApplyController.processForm(EmpLeaveApplyController.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

does any one know how to solve it.

Comment: It seems leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves() returns null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this exception when you try to parse a `null` to a `Double` using the `Double.parseDouble()`. The `getNo_of_leaves()` method seems to be returning `null` and thus the exception.

Either make sure that the value is populated properly and `getNo_of_leaves()` method returns a proper String representation of a Double value (or) make the parsing conditional by adding `null` check prior to it.

```
Double no_of_leaves_form = 0.0; // default value
if(leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves() != null) {
    no_of_leaves_form = Double.parseDouble(leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a null check before trying to parse leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves()

check that leaveapplyform is not null and that leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves() is not null

Answer (score 1):

I suppose leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves() returns null, and can't be parsed as Double.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a conditional check like this:

```
Double no_of_leaves_form == null ?
 null : Double.parseDouble(leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves());
```

Answer (score 0):

catch `NullPointerException` will not throw `Exception`

```
try {
    Double no_of_leaves_form=Double.parseDouble(leaveapplyform.getNo_of_leaves());
}catch(NullPointerException e) {

}
```